ApexPages.addMessage can only be called from a Visualforce page 500 error when calling an Apex REST service
My company currently has a Salesforce app that creates a Lead in our Salesforce system. The app has a Visualforce page with a link to click on for creating a Lead. Clicking the link calls the method processLeadCreation(), which in turn calls two methods: createLead() and createLeadfromAgentServiceWrappers(). createLead() creates a Lead object and fills it with data from a wrapper class supplied as an argument. createLeadfromAgentServiceWrappers() is the method that actually inserts the Lead into our database. Everything is working fine for that app.
We are now creating an additional app with React/Next.js that will also be able to create a Lead and insert it into our database. For that I need to create and expose an endpoint for processLeadCreation() method that can be accessed and used by the new app. I have created a class to add the endpoint and am trying to test it in Postman. When I test it, the endpoint is successfully hit and processLeadCreation() begins running, and it appears that the first inner method, createLead(), successfully runs, but within the second inner method, createLeadfromAgentServiceWrappers() I am getting a 500 error that states:
ApexPages.addMessage can only be called from a Visualforce page

Here is my code:
AgentRequestService.cls
public static void processLeadCreation(AgentServiceWrapper wrapper) {
    Lead newLead = createLead(wrapper);
    createLeadfromAgentServiceWrappers(newLead);
}

public static Lead createLead(AgentServiceWrapper wrapper) {
    Lead lead = new Lead();

    lead.FirstName = wrapper.name.firstName;
    // population of a lot of info
    lead.Party_Id__c = Integer.valueOf(wrapper.partyId);
    lead.Lead_Type__c = 'Lead';
    return lead;
}

public static void createLeadfromAgentServiceWrappers(Lead lead) {
    List<String> objectIdsCreated = new List<String>();
    Savepoint savePoint;

    try {

        savePoint = Database.setSavepoint();

        // Create the lead.
        Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(new SObject[] {
                lead });

        // Check results.
        for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            if (results[i].isSuccess()) {
                objectIdsCreated.add(results[i].getId());
                System.debug('====> AgentRequestService.createLeadFromAgentServiceWrapper() Successfully created ID: ' + results[i].getId());
            } else {
                System.debug('====> AgentRequestService.createLeadFromAgentServiceWrapper() Error: could not create sobject for array element ' + i + ', The error reported was: '
                        + results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage() + '\n');
                throw (new DmlException('Error: could not create sobject for array element ' + i + ', The error reported was: ' + results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage() + '\n'));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (savePoint != null) Database.rollback(savePoint);
        System.debug('createLeadFromAgentServiceWrapper exception = ' + ex);
        ErrorTrapping.logStandardException('AgentRequestService - method: createLeadfromAgentServiceWrappers()', ex);
        throw(ex);
    }
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
    leads.add(lead);
}

AgentRequestServiceRestResource.cls
@RestResource(urlMapping='/agent-service-request')
global with sharing class AgentRequestServiceRestResource {
    /**
     * Get method handler
     */
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {
        System.debug('=====> AgentRequestServiceRestResource.doPost() Entering');
        AgentServiceWrapper agentRqstSrvcRestResponseWrapper = new AgentServiceWrapper();
        List<PMAPIRestResponseWrapper.ErrorMessage> pmapiErrors;
        RestRequest restRequest = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse restResponse = RestContext.response;
        restResponse.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        String paramRequestType = '';
        String requestBodyString = '';
        String sourceIPAddress = restRequest.remoteAddress;

        try {
            requestBodyString = restRequest.requestBody.toString();
            System.debug('=====> AgentRequestServiceRestResource.doPost() requestBodyString=' + requestBodyString);

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(requestBodyString)) {
                restResponse.statusCode = 400;
                return;
            }
            AgentServiceWrapper agentServiceWrapper = (AgentServiceWrapper) JSON.deserialize(requestBodyString, AgentServiceWrapper.class);
            AgentRequestService.processLeadCreation(agentServiceWrapper);
            restResponse.statusCode = 201;
            restResponse.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            restResponse.statusCode = 500;
            System.debug('=====> AgentRequestServiceRestResource.doPost() exception=' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


This question is similar to: Catching exception and posting it back on the page. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From the source code displayed here it appears as if you don't understand where from / why addMessage is called at all, now that you launch the insert based on the POST call. But can't you see this from the stack trace? Your catch block should document the problem in greater detail than to just return the error message. It's better to avoid catch-all catch blocks that even catch implementation errors.
